# Python TypeError 'str object is not callable' when plotting a line plot

Tags: python

Python newbie here. I am trying to display a line plot. The values are taken from a pandas dataframe df_CI. I can't figure out why I get this error.

```
df_CI.index = df_CI.index.map(int) #change the index values of df_CI to type integer for plotting
df_CI.plot(kind='line')

plt.title('Immigrants from China and India')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.xlabel('Whatever')


plt.show()
```

The error I get is:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

I am not referring to anything called 'str'. The plot displays but not the labels:

[image: error and graph]

Comment: One of the functions you're calling is actually a string somewhere. Use `type` to find out which one

Comment: That error is useless without the actual stacktrace, line or anything else. Please provide the _full_ error so we can actually have a chance to figure out the issue.

Comment: @RandomDavis I just added a screenshot if that helps

Comment: @Janet did you do `plt.title = 'something'` earlier in your code? This would have set the `plt.title` to a string and you can't use it as a function after you set it to a string.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Good thinking but no, I haven't. `plt.title`, `plt.ylabel` or `plt.xlabel` is an attribute from module `matplotlib.pyplot` when imported as 
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
so I haven't assigned it any other value

Comment: @Janet I know what `plt` refers to. [This is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07eaE.png): The first line overwrites matplotlib's `title()` by setting `plt.title` to a string. The second line tries to call `plt.title()` as a function, but it's already a string so it can't be called. Make sure there isn't a line in your code earlier that does what I showed on line 1.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes I understood your question. I searched the entire notebook and nowhere such a definition is present `plt.title = xxxx`

Comment: Can you execute `print(plt.title)` in your notebook before you do `plt.title('...')`? This should print `<function title at 0x.....>` if everything is correct. If not, it'll simply print the value of the string that `title` has been set to. Then it's a matter of finding out _where_ this happens.

Comment: If you're using a notebook, the best thing to do when that hapens is to reset it so you have no residue of old cells

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You are right. It did print a value. I couldn't find where in the notebook this value has been assigned. Probably a residue of some old cell. But it has a value so no wonder I get this error. I'll reset my notebook. Thanks all